# MySQL illegal mix of collations in view

Tags: mysql

I know there are dozens of similar questions to this, but I've tried all sorts of suggestions and nothing works.

I have a database that's set to `utf8_unicode_ci` and all tables and columns are also set to `utf8_unicode_ci` (I've checked and double checked).

I've created a view that joins several tables -- my problem is that when I query the view with `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` it's listing several (all from the same table) as `utf8_general_ci` -- even though showing the columns from that single table shows them all to be `utf8_unicode_ci`.

I've also checked that the server and connection are also set to `utf8_unicode_ci` using `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%collation'`

I'm at a loss as to what to try next. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved... it turns out I was using a custom function to apply uppercase on the first letter of words in some columns. This was resulting in the change in collation.

It may be possible to alter the function so it doesn't screw with the collation, but for now I'm just not using it.